# Can't access local ASP.net application from Android emulator

Tags: asp.net, android-emulator, iis-express

I have a simple ASP.net application running locally on IIS express. I use Visual Studio to start IIS express and to deploy the application. I have also  installed locally a Visual Studio Emulator for Android and try to reach this ASP.net application through the emulator's webbrowser. I use the IP from Emulator Adapter #2. However I always get this:

[image]

I know that I have to add an entry into the applicationhost.config:

```
<site name="WebApplication1" id="2">
     <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
     <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="D:\WebApplication1\WebApplication1" />
     </application>
     <bindings>
     <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:1277:localhost" />
     <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:1277:192.168.1.107" />
     </bindings>
</site>
```

I have googled for hours and have tried those additional tricks:

- I have disabled the Windows Firewall.
- I have started Visual Studio and the Emulator as Administrator.
- I have tried to reach the host system through 10.0.2.2
- I have added: netsh http add urlacl url=http://192.168.1.107:1277/ user=everyone

But nothing helps, I always get connection refused. I use Windows 10, Visual Studio 2015 and the latest emulator version.

Comment: did you try to access http://10.0.2.2:1277 ? that is, if 192.168.1.107 is the address of your host in the LAN

Comment: Yes, as mentioned above.